# How to setup RAID for data and AHCI for OS

Tags: hard-drive, raid, storage

I just bought 4 hard drives containing 4 TB each which I hope to set up in a RAID 10 setup, giving an apparent continuous 8 TB hard drive that is backed up.
I also have a 256 GB SSD and a 1TB Hard drive that I would like to set up separately in AHCI mode such that all of my operating systems are on the 256 GB SSD and some other data (of a different category of data than the RAID array) is on the 1 TB hard drive.
Is this possible or advised?
I have a ASUS P8P67 motherboard which I have tried setting to RAID, but the Intel Rapid Storage menu for setting up the RAID only recognizes 2 of the 4 large hard drives that I want in the RAID.  I'm not quite sure how to get them to be recognized.  They do show up in the BIOS when choosing which hard drives can be used for booting.

Is there any way to get these hard drives recognized and then to set this up to be accessed in all of my operating systems from the SSD without wiping my operating systems?

Comment: Reminder: RAID is not a backup.

Comment: RAID 1 is a copy right? RAID 0 combines two disks as I understand it.  So RAID 10 should take the 16 TB (4x4TB HDs) and make it an 8 TB hard drive that is copied (i.e. backed up in case of hard drive failure) right?

Comment: RAID doesn't protect you against, for example, deleting all the files. It's not a backup. It protects you against drive failure, provided you are using RAID with redundancy. This is different.